# Is there any sense in using the <title> tag in HTML e-mail?

Tags: email, html-email

When sending an HTML e-mail, is there any sense in using the `<title>` tag? In the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), for instance, they use such a tag in their main sample code. However, I see no reason why an e-mail client would use this title and not the Subject from the e-mail. Is there any reason to set this tag?

Comment: Seems it is used by some clients: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2010/09/hotmail-mobile-displays-html-title-in-preview/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been looking into this myself as I'm writing a PHP mailing list manager script that uses the `sendmail()` function.

The script allows the admin to create and send multiform emails (both text and html versions).

After much testing I have found that some email servers appear to have issues with the title tag (`<title></title>`).

I created a test email and sent it to 5 of my email address, my `@blueyonder.co.uk` email failed to arrive but the 4 others had no problems.

After a process of elimination it turned out that the `@blueyonder.co.uk` mail servers did not like the title tags in the html part of the email message, when I removed the tag the email arrived no probs.

Very strange!

Comment: 'some email servers appear to have issues' is very vague. What issues? Were the email accepted by the remote SMTP server? Did the emails bounce, if so, on what basis were they rejected?

Comment: @mikemaccana they did not arrive so i can only guess rejected!

Comment: if you sent the mail and it wasn't deliverable you should have a bounce message with details.

Comment: SHOULD being the word! but nothing at all.. im guessing this would apply to all virginmedia mail accounts also as the took over blueyonder.. I also have to stress that this is an old post now and i have not tried it since and virginmedia use google mail now.

Comment: Random spam filters of a specific minor provider generalize very poorly to the rest of the Internet. I'm sure if you search for long enough you can find an ISP which blocks messages which are exactly 4096 bytes long, or anything which contains the letter `z`.

Answer (score 8):

The only use I would see is that some clients, like Outlook, allow you to view an email in a browser for better rendering. It would then be a plus to have the html title tag set.

Answer (score 5):

*(Old question, I know ;) )*

My experience is that some mail clients will display the `<title>` tag in their email preview and some won't. Some clients preview will be "Subject + `<title>` + Preheader" and some will only be "Subject + preheader", so that creates an inconsistent experience.

Because of that, I found it's better to only use a preheader.

---

For completion's sake, the "Preheader" is a hidden text form the body that is only used in the preview, for example, something like...

```html
<div style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  Insert hidden preheader text here
</div>
```